# Subquery left join refer to parent ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to make a query to fetch the newest car for each user:

```
select * from users 
    left join 
       (select cars.* from cars 
        where cars.userid=users.userid 
        order by cars.year desc limit 1) as cars
    on cars.userid=users.userid
```

It looks like it says Unknown column "users.userid" in where clause
I tried to remove cars.userid=users.userid part, but then it only fetches 1 newest car, and sticks it on to each user.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm after? thanks!!

Comment: could you please post the create tables and also some data, so that we can undesrstand your problem better see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to filter the `left join` with a subquery:

```
select * -- better enumerate the columns here
from users u
left join cars c 
    on  c.userid = u.userid
    and c.year = (select max(c1.year) from cars c1 where c1.userid = c.userid)
```

For performance, consider an index on `car(userid, year)`.

Note that this might return multiple cars per user if you have duplicate `(userid, year)` in `cars`. It would be better to have a real date rather than just the year.

Comment: That works very well!  Very nice solution, I didn't think to use an AND on a join statement.  thanks a lot!  Seems to be very fast too

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose, I usually use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from users u left join
     (select c.* , row_number() over (partition by c.userid order by c.year desc) as seqnum
      from cars c
     ) c 
     on c.userid = u.userid and c.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer.  I get 
```
"error in SQL syntax... near '(partition by c.userid order by c.year desc) as seqnum from cars c) c"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are better and more efficient way to query this. Here is my solution;

```
select users.userid, cars.*
from users
         left join cars on cars.userid = users.userid
         join (SELECT userid, MAX(year) AS maxDate
               FROM cars
               GROUP BY userid) as sub on cars.year = sub.maxDate;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but it looks like it returns more than one car per user.